# C++ strange compile linker error

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile large C++ project and I am getting this strange error. I know that it is linking error but couldn't figure out what it is exactly.

```
test_oqlquery.o:(.rodata._ZTV8r_MarrayIhE[vtable for r_Marray]+0x8): undefined reference to r_Marray<unsigned char>::~r_Marray()'
test_oqlquery.o:(.rodata._ZTV8r_MarrayIhE[vtable for r_Marray<unsigned char>]+0xc): undefined reference tor_Marray::~r_Marray()'
test_oqlquery.o:(.rodata._ZTV8r_MarrayIhE[vtable for r_Marray]+0x28): undefined reference to `r_Marray::print_status(std::basic_ostream >&) const'
```

What does this error mean ? And, is it possible to see the line number where there error is happening ? How ? I am mainly concerned with what this means

```
".rodata._ZTV8r_MarrayIhE[vtable for r_Marray]+0x28"
```

Actually, my error is like this, but dont know why everything inside angle bracket are missing, so replacing them with " ", here is detailed error, it has something to do with template instantiation, as well

`` test_oqlquery.o:(.rodata._ZTV8r_MarrayIhE[vtable for r_Marray"unsigned char"]+0x8): undefined reference to `r_Marray"unsigned char"::~r_Marray()' ``

I am using g++ 4.3.3.

Please excuse me, I cannot submit the whole source code here as it is very large and spans over multiple directories.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you give me some idea about template instantiation as well ?

Comment: Could you post the code where you have ~r_Marray and print_status defined? They are in the r_Marray header file right?

Comment: I checked the header file and yes, it has those methods defined but are virtual. This class is derived from another class and defines the print_status method in base class. While looking at sources, I came across file.icc, what is it supposed to contain ? And, how does forward declaration works if I have class in another dir A and I am using that class in dir B soruce file ?

Comment: Since, this header files includes many other header files and many methods are defined in base class, I have to check each header file to know what is wrong. This is why, I am unable to post the source code.

Comment: Forward declaration does not care where the class is actually declared. That being said, it may be tough to forward declare if you actually need to use the class in a header file since you are using templates.

Comment: Sorry but without seeing some code or having more information it is going to be hard to be of much help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, linker errors and compiler errors are different things. Since linker deals with object files rather than source files, compiler errors have a line number but linker errors don't.

Second, it seems that you have declared the destructor for **r_Marray** but have not implemented it anywhere included in the build. The same thing goes for **print_status**.

Comment: Another common reason for link errors like this is incorrect linking order. For example, if print_status and destructor are defined in libMarray.a, then 'g++ -lMarray test_oldquery.o' would produce such an error.

Answer (score 4):

Either you have not defined **r_Marray::~r_Marray()** and **r_Marray::print_status** or the cpp file containing these methods were not part of your build process.

If you do have the cpp file with these methods defined, please post your Makefile.

Based on your comment to your question I am assuming that r_Marray is templated class? Do you have the definitions for the r_Marray methods in your header file?

Answer (score 2):

This typically happens if you have declared a method but haven't provided or haven't linked its implementation.

For example you have

```
class r_Marray {
public:
    ~r_Marray();
};
```

and you intended to provide the implementation of r_Marray::~r_Marray() in file r_Marray.cpp but forgot to do it - it will compile fine but not link with the error you see. Or you could have provided the implementation but not include the file with that implementation into the input of the linker.